# Magento product visibility per customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm looking for a solution to make products visibile/invisible per customer. There are some extension to limit the visibility of products per customer group, but I cant find a solution to set the visibility per customer.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

One way is integrating the extension as mentioned in the question itself.

A work-around would be to add a custom product attribute and we can add a code to check the logged-in customer group in the

`app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

using

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();`

and load the product collection which would filter out the products on the basis of the custom attributes using

`$collection->addAttributeToFilter();`

In my opinion this would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I know how to fix this for a customer group. But I'm looking for a solution to set the product visibility per customer, not customer group.

Comment: But on what basis would the customer be differentiated for the product to be visible?